# Retrieving a PFX certificate from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a third party (Google REST API) certificate on my local system which allows me to request a google access token for API methods. I would like to upload this certificate to Azure Key Vault so I can access and utilize it for automation scripts. Here is an example of my code:

```
$scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
$cert_path = "C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name.pfx>"
$iss = '<name_of_google_service_account'
$cert_pswd = 'google_cert_password'

$accessToken = get_goauth_access_token -scope $scope -cert_path $cert_path -cert_pswd $cert_pswd -iss $iss
```

This code snippet is successful and I receive an access token from Google API. Next, I take my 'cert_name.pfx' and upload it to Azure Key Vault and request access to it in my script:

```
$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $key_vault_name -Name "gsuite-cert" -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($pfxSecret)
$x509Cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($secretByte, $null, [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)

# Write to a file
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name>.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
$cert_path_2 = ""C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name>.pfx""
$cert_pswd_2 = '<cert_secret>'

$access_token = get_goauth_access_token_2 -scope $scope -cert_path $cert_path_2 -cert_pswd $cert_pswd_2 -iss $iss
```

The code being used here is being 'borrowed' from this MS document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-powershell

This second operation fails. I am running the same function with what 'should' be the exact same file, just pulled from Key Vault instead of a local system. So why would the output be different? Does key vault transform my file in some way, or am I just accessing it wrong? Is there a way to get the 'raw' pfx file from key vault, or should I just use a storage account instead?

Comment: Did you mean to use double-double quotes here `$cert_path_2 = ""C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name>.pfx""` ? That will probably just try and launch the cert importer. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I was looking at it again this morning after pulling nearly an all nighter... There was a set of double quotes AND I placed an incorrect 'hard coded value' in one of my definitions for the cert password. Which would explain the error I received, which was 'incorrect network password'.

Short to say, my fault. Silly typo and it is now fixed. Thank you so much anyway! Sometimes an extra hint is all you need. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment and got the similar error like below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, while exporting the file I removed the two double quotes like below:

```
$vaultName = 'testrukkv'
$certificateName = 'testrukpfx'
$password = 'xxx!'

$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($pfxSecret)
$x509Cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$x509Cert.Import($secretByte, $null, [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)

[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\kvruk.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
Write-Host "Exported certificate successfully"
```

[image]

The file got exported successfully like below:

[image]

I agree with *@Cpt.Whale*, **to resolve the error modify your code** like below:

```
$pfxSecret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $key_vault_name -Name "gsuite-cert" -AsPlainText
$secretByte = [Convert]::FromBase64String($pfxSecret)
$x509Cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($secretByte, $null, [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxFileByte = $x509Cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)

# Write to a file
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name>.pfx", $pfxFileByte)
$cert_path_2 = "C:\Users\Desktop\<cert_name>.pfx"
$cert_pswd_2 = '<cert_secret>'

$access_token = get_goauth_access_token_2 -scope $scope -cert_path $cert_path_2 -cert_pswd $cert_pswd_2 -iss $iss
```